# Teamcity deploy using MSBuild to network path, only works when destination is empty

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a build step on TeamCity, that builds a project file and deploys the project to a network location. //server/system/Web

When the web folder does not exist, the deployment works fine, however, if the web folder already exists, the web folder is just deleted and the build fails.

Is there a flag I need to set, so msbuild just replaces the content, if there is anything there. I have also considered a powershell script that removes all content from the folder, before deploying, is this a viable solution?

LOG:

[12:20:18][MSBuild output] CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeploy:

[12:20:18][MSBuild output]   Creating directory "\server\system\web".

[12:20:18][MSBuild output]   Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:

[12:20:18][MSBuild output]   \server\system\web.

[12:20:18][MSBuild output]   Copying bin\Dokumentproduksjon.Web.dll to \server\system\web\bin\Dokumentproduksjon.Web.dll.

[12:20:18][MSBuild output]   Create Folder \server\system\web\bin failed. Access to the path '\server\system\web\bin' is denied.

[12:20:18][MSBuild output] Done Building Project "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\ac656796ad82c0\Dokumentproduksjon.Web\Dokumentproduksjon.Web.csproj.teamcity" (Build;Package target(s)) -- FAILED.

[12:20:18][MSBuild output]

[12:20:18][MSBuild output] Build FAILED.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a deployment to production or into a testing environment?

If it's production, is it possible that you are serving up the content and that it is therefore locked? Is IIS / Apache serving up the content?

If it's into a testing environment, the same could be true, have you verified it's not being hosted? Typically the ideal situation is to deploy to a clean Virtual Machine, ensuring that you are deploying as if it were a new environment. That will get you around the problem of the `web` folder existing already. If you do not have that luxury, then you want to run scripts first that make this environment mimic a clean environment, so yes, you would want a command to drop that folder. However, back to the comment earlier, if something has a file lock on that folder your command will fail as well.

Comment: Its to test, system is not yet in production. Workaround as of now, is to have a PS script remove the folder, this always works. The scripts is being run as a build step in TeamCity. It works, but it feels unnescessary, howver it has given me the oppertunity to move old files to backup location, instead of just replacing. 

I also get the problem, if the web folder is empty, meaning it should not be file lock, its also only a problem when accessing the path as a network path.

Thanks for suggestion though :)